# Ionic AppFlow - Build with iOS Push Notifications

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-appflow

I am building an app via AppFlow for both iOS and Android. The app supports push notifications.

Both Android and iOS build successfully. The Android version works as expected, and push notifications are functional. On iOS, push notifications are NOT functional.

Does anyone have any thoughts on how to configure the certificate for AppFlow such that iOS will build with Push Notification allowances?

I am not familiar with building iOS apps (thus the reason I'm using AppFlow) and am unsure how to proceed.

---

To clarify after more research on my part, I need to accomplish two things:

- Configure the Push Notification entitlement.
- Associate the Google Services plist file with the iOS build.

Both tasks must be done without xcode (since I'm using appflow to build)

Comment: what appFlow version are you using?  do you have an IOS Id to use ? and an ionic pro acount?

Comment: I am also having same issue

Answer (score 0):

We use `phonegap-plugin-push` for notifications, and that plugin takes care of the Push Notification entitlement. Within the plugin's `plugin.xml`, there is an entry:

```
  <platform name="ios">
    <config-file target="config.xml" parent="/*">
      <feature name="PushNotification">
        <param name="ios-package" value="PushPlugin"/>
      </feature>
    </config-file>
```

To add the Google Services plist file, include the following entry in `config.xml`, within the ios platform:

```
<platform name="ios">
    <resource-file src="GoogleService-Info.plist" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Remember, Push notifications don’t work in a simulator, so you’ll need an actual device

You have to get the [IOS Credentials](https://ionicframework.com/docs/appflow/package/credentials), register device and then get the certificate.

1. Configure your app and register it with the Apple Push Notification service (APNs).
2. Send a push notification from a server to specific devices via APNs.
3. Use callbacks in the app to receive and handle push notifications.

Once done you can [Publish to Appstore](https://ionicframework.com/docs/publishing/app-store)

Using [swift](https://ionicframework.com/docs/appflow/package/credentials) is another better option to implement push notifications.